# Как это вычислить?

Tags: php, дата

Всем привет, есть задача надо взять дату

time()

и прибавить в ней 24 часа(т.е 1 сутки), я видел подубную формулу

```
$date = time() + 1 * 24 * 3600
```

Так вот расскажите, я не совсем понимаю как это вычисляется?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `time()` возвращает количество секунд прошедших с 1 января 1970г., по формуле можно догадаться что `1` это сутки, `24` - это количество часов в сутках, `3600` - количество секунд в одном часу, так что по формуле вычисляется через сколько секунд пройдёт через сутки начиная с января 1970г.

Comment: Спасибо, наконец-то я понял это :=)

Answer (score 2):

Лучше так:

```
strtotime('+1 day');
```

Comment: Ух ты! Классная функция, спасибо.